# Launching runnable objects in threads out of a C++ std::vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stdthread

I have a C++11 program which configures a number of runnable objects, puts them in  a `std::vector`, then launches them all in separate threads. Unfortunately when I iterate over the objects in the vector, I am getting threads launched only for the last object. I've distilled the problem to its core in the following test code (compiled with `clang++ -std=c++11 cpp_threadlaunch.cpp` using `clang` 6.0 on OSX 10.9.5).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>

std::mutex  outputlock;

class agent {

public:
    agent(std::string name) : m_name(name) {};
    ~agent(void) {};

    void run(void) {
        while (1) {
            outputlock.lock();
            std::cout << "Agent: " << m_name << std::endl;
            outputlock.unlock();
            sleep(1);
        }
    }
    std::string     getName(void) { return m_name; }

private:

    std::string     m_name;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread>        threads;
    std::vector<agent*>             agents;
    // std::string                  goal = "succeed";
    std::string                     goal = "fail";

    agents.push_back(new agent("A"));
    agents.push_back(new agent("B"));

    if (goal == "succeed") {

        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { agents.at(0)->run(); }));
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { agents.at(1)->run(); }));

    }
    else {

        for (auto it = agents.begin(); it != agents.end(); it++) {

            agent* a = *it;

            std::cout << "Launching thread for " << a->getName() << std::endl;

            threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() { a->run(); }));
        }
    }

    for (auto it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end(); it++) {

        it->join();
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

When I run with `goal = "succeed"`, I get the hoped-for output

```
Agent: A
Agent: B
Agent: A
Agent: B
```

When I run with `goal = "fail"`, I get two copies of the output from only one object, instead of output from each object:

```
Launching thread for A
Launching thread for B
Agent: B
Agent: B
Agent: B
Agent: B
```

I suspect I'm missing something rudimentary here -- would much appreciate it if someone can explain what's going on and what the solution is. Thanks --

Comment: Please indent your code... less.

Comment: I'd recommend `emplace_back` instead of `push_back(new ...)`.

Comment: Also you can use a `std::for_each` to join the threads. :)

Comment: @erip, thanks -- why `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`?

Comment: `emplace_back` [saves you a move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lambda function you're passing to `std::thread` in the loop captures `a` by reference. Since `a` then goes out of scope you have undefined behavior. Capture it by value (using `[=]` instead of `[&]`).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you capture the value of 'a' by reference in
    `[&]() { a->run() }`
You see the last value, because the loop has finished, by the time the other threads run.
If you capture by value, using [=] you should get the desired effect.

Comment: Did you add something what the other answer didn't have or did you just post the same, but without formatting?

Comment: There was no other answer here, when I posted mine.

Comment: It says the other answer is 10 minutes older and you could have refreshed the page while typing yours. I don't post if someone beats me to the seconds.

Comment: It is just my first time answering. I was assuming it worked in a more sensible way than that.